# Tick script with multiple tag values

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I have a tick script where I have to run query with where clause on multiple interface_name which looks something like this:

```
query('''SELECT last("state") as "value" FROM router.autogen.cisco_router where type = 'interface' and host = '10.66.14.82' and ("name"='GigabitEthernet0/0/0' OR "name"='GigabitEthernet0/0/1') ''')
```

and this query run on influx db but kapacitor change this query to something like this:

```
`SELECT last("state") as "value" FROM router.autogen.cisco_router where type = 'interface' and host = '10.66.14.82' and (\"name\"='GigabitEthernet0/0/0' OR \"name\"='GigabitEthernet0/0/1')`
```

how to avoid `\` befor `"` in tick script.

Comment: is `name` a tag?

Comment: yes it is, i was able to solve problem after creating new tag name interface_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any answer so i created a new tag with a different name and it solved the problem.